# Using Next.js next-routes, how to define a home route for the base web page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When using next-routes, and turning off default /page routing

```
useFileSystemPublicRoutes: true
```

how can you get the root page of a web site to display?

I can't seem to get any base route to work. For example, this route:

```
routes.add("homeRoute",'/','homePage');
```

does not seem to may from locahost:3000/

I see an issue here in the repo that I think is similar but with no solution.

https://github.com/fridays/next-routes/issues/228

Comment: u using next 7 right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think instead of `useFileSystemPublicRoutes: true` you just need to create a custom [server.js](https://github.com/fridays/next-routes#on-the-server)

```
// server.js
const next = require('next');
const routes = require('./routes');
const app = next({ dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' });
const handler = routes.getRequestHandler(app);

const { createServer } = require('http');
app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(handler).listen(3000);
});
```

and then have a routes.js

```
// routes.js
const routes = require('next-routes');

module.exports = routes().add({
  name: 'homeRoute',
  pattern: '/',
  page: 'homePage'
});
```

Run `node server.js` and test `/` path.