# Setting up the home page on Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Does anybody know **how to define any specific page in Next.js as the root (the home page)**?

I have been looking online and was not able to find any concrete solutions. This is suppose to be a very common use case.

There is this other post, [Using Next.js next-routes, how to define a home route for the base web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52601724/using-next-js-next-routes-how-to-define-a-home-route-for-the-base-web-page), but it recommends creating a server for it.

Is there any "NextJs" way of setting up a Home Page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is the solution offered by nextjs.

Create or edit the file `next.config.js` in the root directory:

```js
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/about',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects

Answer (score 4):

“When a file is added to the pages directory it's automatically available as a route.

The files inside the pages directory can be used to define most common patterns.”

> The router will automatically route files named
> index to the root of the directory.

`pages/index.js` → `/`

More details: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction

Comment: Thanks Emin! But how do you set the home page when you need it to be something else? For example, mywebsite.com/ ==> mywebsite.com/posts/my-post-1. In Next.js my-post-1 is a dynamic route.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction#injecting-the-router (—) https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

Answer (score 1):

I posted the answer that solved my issue in this other thread:

[Next.js Redirect from / to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173809/next-js-redirect-from-to-another-page/63278361#63278361)

The example was taken from
https://dev.to/justincy/client-side-and-server-side-redirection-in-next-js-3ile

I needed to immediately forward the user who visited my root page (mywebsite.com/) to a subpage, in this case Home: mywebsite.com/home

Pasting either of the following in my main index.js file, achieves the desired result:

There are copy-paste-level examples for

Client Side

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function RedirectPage() {
  const router = useRouter()
  // Make sure we're in the browser
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    router.push('/home')
  }
}

export default RedirectPage
```

Server Side

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function RedirectPage({ ctx }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  // Make sure we're in the browser
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    router.push('/home');
    return; 
  }
}

RedirectPage.getInitialProps = ctx => {
  // We check for ctx.res to make sure we're on the server.
  if (ctx.res) {
    ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/home' });
    ctx.res.end();
  }
  return { };
}

export default RedirectPage
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a page.jsx file in the App Router directory.

As of NextJS version 13, app/page.jsx replaces pages/index.js.

For more, see https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#step-2-creating-a-root-layout.

[image: Pages and App Directories Defined Routes]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a different basePath configured and wants to redirect / to a specific page then make sure to set basePath:false in redirects method in config else / will through 404

In next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    async redirects() {
        return [
          {
            source: '/',
            destination:'/<your basePath>/ui/auth/login',
            permanent: true,
            basePath:false
          },
        ]
      },
    assetPrefix: '<your prefix>',
    basePath: '<your basePath>',
    //For both Server side and client side secretes
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`page.js` should work as a homepage on each level.

https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/page